# Neo4j AWS installation failing to load apoc jar

Tags: amazon-ec2, neo4j

I've a neo4j instance installed using community AMI and it keeps complaining with below error, even though I've configured Bolt accept non-local connections i.e. dbms.connector.bolt.address=0.0.0.0:7687

```
 Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected hostname at index 7: bolt://:7687
        at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.failExpecting(URI.java:2854)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHostname(URI.java:3390)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parseServer(URI.java:3236)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parseAuthority(URI.java:3155)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3097)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3053)
        at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:673)
        at org.neo4j.server.rest.discovery.DiscoverableURIs$Builder.add(DiscoverableURIs.java:128)
        ... 15 more
```

I've installed following version

AWS AMI id : ami-0118d82e9da26d491
Neo4j version: 3.5.3

Is this a known issue, thanks in advance

Comment: can you share also the content of the `neo4j.log` ?

Comment: Those are neo4j log

Comment: you have shared the `debug.log` not the `neo4j.log`

Comment: I do not have neo4j.log in /var/log/neo4j directory

Comment: I noticed that while restarting neo4j I get below warning 
/usr/share/neo4j/bin/neo4j: line 451: /var/run/neo4j/neo4j.pid: No such file or directory
/usr/share/neo4j/bin/neo4j: line 450: /var/log/neo4j/neo4j.log: Permission denied

that could be a reason my service is not getting started

Comment: I created the folder `/var/run/neo4j` and tried starting ne04j instance using sudo command, now I've following error :  java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected hostname at index 7: bolt://:7687
Although I've bolt configured

Comment: Can you share your neo4j.conf ?